# call to one of my codeigniter controller is returning 404 error my code is ok

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

When I send my url `http://localhost:8080/myScholarship/register` to the server, i get a 404 error. My controller name is `Register` and the file name is saved with `Register.php`. and am calling the `index()` function.

This is my controller:

```
<?php
class Register extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('pages/index');
    }

    /****************************************create*************************************/
    public function create()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //$data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname', 'Surname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Firstname', 'required');
        //$this->form_validation->set_rules('othername', 'Othername', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phonenumber', 'Phonenumber', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'confirmpassword', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            //$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('index');
            //$this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        elseif($this->input->post('password') != $this->input->post('confirmpassword')){
            $data1 = "the password does not match";
            $this->load->view('index',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $file_data = '';
            if((isset($_FILES['recentphoto']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['recentphoto']['name']))){
                $file_data = './uploads/'.$_FILES['recentphoto']['name'];
            }else{
                $file_data = './uploads/images.jpg';
            }
            $file = do_upload();
            if(isset($file['error'])){
                $data1 = $file['error'];
                $this->load->view('index',$data1);
            }else{
            $this->news_model->set_applicant($file['upload_data']);
            $succ = "please login with your account details";
            $this->load->view('index',$succ);
            }
        }
    }
    /*************************************end create***************************************/
    public function do_upload()
    {
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['max_size']             = 100000;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('recentphoto'))
            {
                  return $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    //$this->load->view('upload/upload', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                   return $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    //$this->load->view('upload/upload_success', $data);
            }
    }
}
?>
```

This is my `routes.php`:

```
<?php
$route['register'] = 'register';
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
?>
```

Comment: Do some debugging to try to find out at what point it's failing. For example, insert `die('asd')` in the constructor and see if you see the output. If you do, try the same in the `index()` method. If you never see it, there's a deeper problem. I've had problems before with CI filenaming conventions but from what you say the file and the class are named properly.

Comment: I tried putting a die() function in the constructor and still no change, am just totally confused this has really taken me to long to solve

Answer (score 0):

If you work in a server Linux/Unix you can remember that file names ar case sensitive, try with url `http://localhost:8080/myScholarship/Register` or change the name of controller to **register.php** without upper letter **R**

**EDIT**

Change yours routes to:

```
<?php
$route['register'] = 'register/index';
$route['register/(:any)'] = 'register/$1';
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['pages/view/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Try.

Comment: I just tried all you said and am still getting no difference yet, i really need to fix this

Answer (score 0):

In **Route.php** file its necessary to define function name (index) also, please use this routing.

```
$route['register'] = 'register/index';
```

**instead of**

```
$route['register'] = 'register';
```

If still its not worked then may be it will be the issues of htaccess file, try also url like that.

```
http://localhost:8080/myScholarship/index.php/register
```

If above url working fine, it means there is htaccess issue.